# rewrite subdomain using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

My main domain is `subdomain.domain.tld`, and I want to rewrite all the traffic from `subdomain1.domain.tld` to the first one. Meaning if someone accesses `subdomain1.domain.tld/whatever.php`, he actually accesses `subdomain.domain.tld/whatever.php`, however, he's still shown `subdomain1` in the browser's navigation bar.

I did some research, but I couldn't find something too promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need rewriting for this, in fact internal rewriting is not possible between separate hosts...

Assuming that both "subdomains" (those are actually hostnames) are served by the same http server you can simply configure the same `DocumentRoot` for both hosts. That way they serve exactly the same file system which obviously means that the same scripts will be called.

Maybe you can get away even more simple if you just use the `ServerAlias` command for your virtual host. This obviously is only possible if you do not need separate configurations for both hosts.

Just take a look into the documentation of the apache http server. This is explained and good examples are offered: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

---

In case those two hosts are *not* served by the same http server you could use an internal proxy setup: `subdomain1.domain.tld` acts as a front end proxy for `subdomain.domain.tld`, so it just relays all incoming requests and also the outgoing responses. That is easily done with a combination of the `ProxyPass` and the `ProxyPassReverse` rules offered by apaches proxy module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse

This setup can even be used if the two http servers operate on different IP addresses or even completely separate systems.